# How to add a constant value to every other column in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am having trouble adding a constant value to every other column in a numpy array. For example, Let's say that I have an array of zeros like:

```
import numpy as np    
a = np.zeros([100,10], dtype=np.int64)
```

and now I want to add a constant, say '50', to every element in every other column. This way I would expect to keep an array that is 10 columns by 100 rows that alternates as 0,50,0,50,0,50... etc

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
>>> a[:, ::2] += 50
```

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np    
>>> a = np.zeros([5,10], dtype=np.int64)
>>> a[:, ::2] += 50
>>> a

array([[50,  0, 50,  0, 50,  0, 50,  0, 50,  0],
       [50,  0, 50,  0, 50,  0, 50,  0, 50,  0],
       [50,  0, 50,  0, 50,  0, 50,  0, 50,  0],
       [50,  0, 50,  0, 50,  0, 50,  0, 50,  0],
       [50,  0, 50,  0, 50,  0, 50,  0, 50,  0]], dtype=int64)
```

For both `row` and `column` you would do:

```
>>> a[::2, ::2] += 50
```

Comment: Thank you! I am new to python and this is very helpful. I have not seen [:, before in an array, what does the colon and comma at the beginning of a[:, ::2] += 50 denote?